# How can I modify my program to continue finding applicable numbers after it uses a set of 3 different numbers?

Tags: java, class

My issue is that even though it is printing out the values and everything correctly, I still need it to test higher values, obviously still less than my max value of my sample input, which is 110.

Here's my code:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Triples
{
  private int first;
  private int second;
  private int third;
  private int number;

  public Triples()
  {
    //this(0);
  }

  public Triples(int num)
  {
    number = num;
  }

  public void setNum(int num)
  {
    number = num;
  }

  private int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b, int c)
  {
    int g;
    int h;

    if(a<b && a<c)
      g = a;
    else if(b< a && b<c)
      g = b;
    else
      g = c;

    for(int i = g; i > 0; i--)
    {
      if((a%i == 0) && (b%i == 0))
      {
        h = i;
        for(int j = i; j>0; j--)
        {
          if((h%j==0) && (c%j == 0))
          {
            return j;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  return -1;
  }


  public String check4Triples()
  {
    int max = number;
    String amIdoneYet;
    //int a;
    //int b;
    //int c;
    for(int n = 1; n <= max; n++)
      //{

      for(int a = n; a <= max; a++)
      {
        first = a;
        for(int b = a +1; b <= max; b++)
        {
          second =b;
          for(int c = b + 1; c <= max; c++)
          {
            third = c;
            if(Math.pow(a, 2)+ Math.pow(b, 2)== Math.pow(c, 2))
            {
              if((a%2==1 && b%2==0)|| (a%2==0 && b%2==1))
              {
                if(this.greatestCommonFactor(a, b, c)== 1)
                {
                  amIdoneYet = "";
                  amIdoneYet += a + " " + b + " "+ c;
                  return amIdoneYet;
                }
              }
            }                   
          }
        }   
      }
      return null;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      String output=" ";
      output += check4Triples() + " \n";

      return output;
    }
  }
```

However, I believe the issue at hand lies in my runner class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab11j
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice="";
    do{
      out.print("Enter the max number to use : ");
      int big = keyboard.nextInt();

      //instantiate a TriangleThree object
      Triples triple = new Triples(big);

      //call the toString method to print the triple
      out.println( triple );

      System.out.print("Do you want to enter more data? ");
      choice=keyboard.next();
    }while(choice.equals("Y")||choice.equals("y"));
  }
}
```

Here's what my output should look like:

- 3 4 5
- 5 12 13
- 7 24 25
- 8 15 17
- 9 40 41
- 11 60 61
- 12 35 37
- 13 84 85
- 16 63 65
- 20 21 29
- 20 99 101
- 28 45 53
- 33 56 65
- 36 77 85
- 39 80 89
- 48 55 73
- 60 91 109
- 65 72 97

**UPDATE**
After think it over some, I think the issue is that the for loops have no way of knowing whether or not to go again... I'm still thinking the issue relates back to my runner class somehow. But in my `check4Triples` method, I essentially only tell it to find the three lowest applicable numbers. I'm not sure how to tell it to check other values as well

Comment: I find the code a little difficult to read, especially with all the vertical and horizontal whitespace.

Comment: I'm not sure how much whitespace you're seeing but the way I intendded to write it was meant to be less pushed together and cleaner-looking

Comment: If anyone finds it necessary, I don't mind if you want to fix the code around to produce less whitespace.... I just don't see any

Comment: The choices of where whitespace goes puzzles me a bit; while I'm very anti-opening-brace-on-newline, IMO that's less of an issue than not surrounding keywords and operators with spaces. Also, deeply-nested structures are very difficult to reason about: code turned on its side is not a graph of how awesome it is.

Comment: The code is almost impossible to read. You should use more descriptive variable names instead of a, b, c, d, g etc. 

Like, int numberToFactor, factor1, factor2, etc.

Not only that, but you have i and j in your nested for loop, which gives the reader 7 total one letter int variables to keep track of.

Comment: I only had it like that because that's how the lab was set up in it's bare-bones format when I started. I won't mind fixing it, even if it's just for this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the issue is that you return a string value immediately upon finding a GCF of one, whereas what you're *trying* to do is loop through up to your max number and find *all* of the triples:

```
if (this.greatestCommonFactor(a, b, c) == 1) {
    return "" + a + " " + b + " "+ c;
}
```

The second issue is that the loop(s) around the incorrect code has an extra loop, `1..n`, which is already handled by `a = 1..n`:

```
for (int n = 1; n <= max; n++) {
    for (int a = n; a <= max; a++) {
        ...
```

Now, you *could* solve this by:

1. Eliminating the extra loop, and
2. Adding the triple to a single string following by a newline.

Personally, I'd use a `List<String>` for this and iterate over the output, but that's a different issue.

We end up with something closer to this:

```
public String check4Triples() {
    int max = number;
    String ret = "";

    for (int a = 1; a <= max; a++) {
        for (int b = a + 1; b <= max; b++) {
            for (int c = b + 1; c <= max; c++) {
                if (isPythagoreanTriple(a, b, c)) {
                    if (mod2(a, b) || mod2(b, a)) {
                        if (greatestCommonFactor(a, b, c) == 1) {
                            ret += "" + a + " " + b + " " + c + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Using `100` as the max number, my output is this:

```
3 4 5
5 12 13
7 24 25
8 15 17
9 40 41
11 60 61
12 35 37
13 84 85
16 63 65
20 21 29
28 45 53
33 56 65
36 77 85
39 80 89
48 55 73
65 72 97
```

Which I believe is closer to what you intend. I might use short-circuit logic, too:

```
if (isPythagoreanTriple(a, b, c)
        && (mod2(a, b) || mod2(b, a))
        && (greatestCommonFactor(a, b, c) == 1)) {
    ret += "" + a + " " + b + " " + c + "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how the line `if (isPythagoreanTriple(a, b, c))` works

Comment: @tech_geek23 That's because I'm not going to give you a completely working program. The logic is the same as what you have now, just more communicative. You don't *need* to change that line in your own code, it just makes it easier to understand. I also added `mod2` and `min` functions to keep my head from asploding.

Comment: Ok, I adjusted my code to the problems you pointed out and it appears to be fully functioning now. was the primary issue the location of my `return amIdoneYet` line?

Comment: @tech_geek23 As I said, the crux of your issue was that, and the extra looping. https://gist.github.com/4157650#file_triples.java